# Scraping a website using selenium error on square-space site

Tags: python, selenium, squarespace

I am trying to scrape a website hosted on Squarespace using the python bindings for selenium that contains a web serial, I am copying the content of a div into a text file. Here is the code I was using to do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
i = 1
while i<250:
    driver.get("http://www.drewhayesnovels.com/spy4/{0}".format(i))
    content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p') #Get content
    content_text = content.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    file = open("output/ch{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
    file.write(str(content_text))
    file.close()
    print(i)
    i = i + 1

print("Complete")
```

For some reason, on the third chapter, it stops being able to find the element. So I wrote this little test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Opera()
i = 1
while i<250:
    driver.get("http://www.drewhayesnovels.com/spy4/{0}".format(i))
    try:
        content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p') #Get content
        content_text = content.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        file = open("output/ch{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
        file.write(str(content_text))
        file.close()
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
    except:
        print("Error, keep running.")
        i = i + 1

print("Complete")
```

Out of this, only 5 or 6 seemingly random pages were successful. I tried it with another browser (Opera) and it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: do you see the error: `list object has no attribute get_attribute`

Comment: I get the error `Unable to locate element`, but I checked the page in Inspect Element and there were no differences except the content I was scraping.

Comment: Just aside, Squarespace sites use json-t and you can actually just access it – http://www.drewhayesnovels.com/spy4?format=json-pretty – then parse the body as html. No scraping needed.

Comment: Oh! great I hope that gives an alternative.